# How to run a .bat file from a TRACE32 script?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I need to run a .bat file from a TRACE32 script.

I tried with OS.FILE.ACCESS("name of file","x") where x represents X execute file.

In the manual it says that this function returns TRUE or FALSE, so I executed PRINT OS.FILE.ACCESS("FILENAME","x") but I only receive TRUE, the .bat file isn't executed.

Is there a posibility to execute a .bat file from a TRACE32 script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you actually want to do, one of the following commands should be suitable to run any external program or batch file:

- `OS.Area <cmdline>`      Output in AREA window (blocking)
- `OS.Window <cmdline>`    Output in "OS.Window" window (blocking)
  inside PowerView
- `OS.screen <cmdline>`    On Windows the command gets directly executed without a shell. The output of a console application is shown in a temporary command window. / On Linux the output is in the shell, which started the TRACE32 GUI (non-blocking)
- `OS.Hidden <cmdline>`    No output anywhere (blocking)
- `OS.Command <cmdline>`   Output in system shell, which allows redirects (non-blocking on Windows / blocking on Linux unless you add an ampersand &)

I'd suggest command `OS.Command <cmdline>`

The Function OS.FILE.ACCESS() is indented to check if you have read/write or execution rights for a file.